# how to write a wsgi wrapper for php applications?

Tags: php, python, apache2, wsgi, werkzeug

Is it possible to write a wsgi ([werkzeug)](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/) application, that returns the output of a php application?

In detail, i have the following problem:
We have a couple of old, legacy php applications and need some sort of authentication in front of it, handled by a wsgi or any other python application.

in dummy code it would work like this:

```
for every request:
    valid = check cookie or get-paramter
    if valid:
        return php application
    else:
        return "<html>you are not allowed</html>"
```

i know there are [access control mechanisms](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/AccessControlMechanisms) for apache-mod_wsgi, but the only allow to return true or false.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

googling for "python wsgi php", the first result I get is http://pythonpaste.org/wphp/ :

> This module allows you to run PHP processes inside of Python, using a WSGI gateway.

but as you mention it never went further than alpha.

A braindead solution would be to serve the php application on a local IP and have your wsgi app just proxy to the php one via urllib, but you'll possibly have to postprocess the reponse body to fix urls etc.

Comment: hmm yeah, i stumbled upon wphp a couple of days ago. unfortunately the project never made it past alpha and is abandoned since 2011.